# google actions icon: does it serve from cache

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have been using google actions with actions sdk and most of the functionality seems to work. However, I am facing consistent issues across a few alpha test users on the updates to the application.

I notice that the latest deployed to the cloud function is what seems to run on the Simulator but an old version appears when viewing on a phone. For example, the icon that I set in the images directory is just not showing (even after 2 days) on my phone while the latest appears in the Simulator. The same with some images from Cloud storage. I tried clearing the cache and storage from the Assistant app on my android phone. Yet the problem persists.

Is there some setting or **disabling of cache** that needs to be specified in the NodeJS based client code or in the actions console? Thanks.

Comment: I seem to notice that it takes the icon that a new user (phone) first time accesses the google action. e.g. if when user 1 accessed the icon was set to icon-1.png. Then, even by changing it, it still shows the same. While if a new user 2 accesses the action for the first time, it shows the new icon.

Comment: The images from google storage seem to be showing after some time, but the action icon shows the first one.

Comment: To further add to the problem, even updates to action settings like voice does not seem to be changing from test devices. It seems like the whole google actions settings (images + voice) seem to be either stored or being fed from an old cache. In fact, I deleted the Google Assistant app from the phone and re-installed it, yet the old icon and voice is being set. While the simulator shows the latest. Anyone else facing such a problem?

Comment: is no one else facing such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Test tab and click on the Reset Test option, such as in the screenshot. It should work.

[image]